# Translate "Total" text in Legend in Crystal Reports Chart

Tags: crystal-reports

When using a chart (e.g. pie chart) inside a Crystal Report with a legend, the legend will contain a line with the sum of the values. The text used for the word "Total" seems to be fixed on the language of the Crystal Reports Library. For example, since I am using a German operating system, the text will always be "Summe".

Is there a way to translate the text or at least to hide it altogether?

For illustration:

[image]

Comment: One hack job way of doing it would be to overlay a solid white text box object over the portion you want to hide. It would only work if your legend doesn't dynamically resize, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

1. Open report in CR.
2. Set report do "Preview Mode" by clicking View -> Print Preview
3. When in "Preview Mode", select the Legend label you want to change the text of.
4. Right click on the Legend label and select "Edit Axis Label"
5. Then, select the chart, right click and select Chart Expert -> Apply template to group.
   6 Save the modified report.

also check this:

http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/1206

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337170%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: I am looking for a solution that can change the text at runtime. Also, I am referring to the "total" text that is automatically added by Crystal Reports.